# Ajustar bordes en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

En mi programa:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var $lista1 = $('#lista1'), $lista2 = $('#lista2');
 // lista 1
 $('li',$lista1).draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',  
  helper: 'clone',  
  cursor: 'move'
 });
 $lista1.droppable({
  accept: '#lista2 li',
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
   deleteLista2(ui.draggable);
  }
 });
 /* lista2 */
 $('li',$lista2).draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  helper: 'clone', 
  cursor: 'move'
 });
 $lista2.droppable({
  accept: '#lista1 > li',
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
   deleteLista1(ui.draggable);  
  }
 });
 // listas 
 function deleteLista1($item) {
  $item.fadeOut(function() {
   $($item).appendTo($lista2).fadeIn();;
  });
  $item.fadeIn();
 }
 function deleteLista2($item) {
  $item.fadeOut(function() {   
   $item.appendTo($lista1).fadeIn();
  });
 }

});
```

```css
body,td,th {
 color: #333333;
}
#lista1, #lista2 {
 width:200px;
 border:1px solid #990000;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo-frame">
<ul id="lista1" class="gallery">
 <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
</ul>
<ul id="lista2">
 <li>Item5</li>
    <li>Item6</li>
    <li>Item7</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Se puede mover las filas de una lista a otra, pero yo lo que quiero es que el borde tenga un espacio, ya que cuando mueves un item y lo pasas a otra lista el borde se va achicando y el problema es que cuando no tiene ningún item una lista este se queda como linea y cuesta trabajo ingresarle un item.

Por favor, necesito su ayuda.

Comment: Ten cuidado ya que el ejemplo que has agregado no es reproducible. De todas formas, podrías calcular la altura de la lista más grande y aplicárselo a la otra mediante Javascript.

Comment: Me podría mostrar un ejemplo por favor, ya que no entiendo muy bien Javascript.

Comment: Si pones un ejemplo que se pueda reproducir puedo ayudarte respecto a tu ejemplo. Ahora mismo tu ejemplo no funciona correctamente.

Comment: Le inserte una libreria y me sigue marcando error @FranciscoRomero, no se como reproducirlo

Comment: Cuando editas el ejemplo hay un botón a la izquierda que pone "Añadir librería externa". Ahí puedes agregarla sin problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario hacerlo con javascript, basta con ponerle un `min-height` al `div` para que no desaparezca al quedarse sin elementos.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $lista1 = $('#lista1'),
    $lista2 = $('#lista2');
  // lista 1
  $('li', $lista1).draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move'
  });
  $lista1.droppable({
    accept: '#lista2 li',
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      deleteLista2(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
  /* lista2 */
  $('li', $lista2).draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move'
  });
  $lista2.droppable({
    accept: '#lista1 > li',
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      deleteLista1(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
  // listas 
  function deleteLista1($item) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      $($item).appendTo($lista2).fadeIn();;
    });
    $item.fadeIn();
  }

  function deleteLista2($item) {
    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      $item.appendTo($lista1).fadeIn();
    });
  }

});
```

```css
body,
td,
th {
  color: #333333;
}

#lista1,
#lista2 {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #990000;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="demo-frame">
  <ul id="lista1" class="gallery">
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="lista2">
    <li>Item5</li>
    <li>Item6</li>
    <li>Item7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias,me solucionaste mi problema, yo no sabia que existiera tal comando para CSS ...